# Replace deprecated sdk/widget, without using toolbar from Australis

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, deprecated, deprecation-warning

Since some time sdk/widget is deprecated and according to https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/03/13/new-add-on-sdk-australis-ui-features-in-firefox-29/ sdk/ui/ should be used instead.

Unfortunately sdk/ui/frame places itself on sdk/ui/toolbar and it may be not moved to main menu. Toolbar is unacceptable for me, but sdk/widget support will be dropped in future - so I need some solution.

For reference - sdk/widget frame (with purple, fully filled progress bars) and a sdk/ui abomination with its own menu below (black, not filled progress bars).

[image]

Comment: Toolbar is the only option via the SDK - you might get other answers using [lower level APIs[(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/CustomizableUI.jsm).

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the widget module and publish it on npm and try to support it.

Just copy and paste it to a new module, remove the deprecation warnings, and publish that on npm, and start using it with [`jpm`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jpm)

[For more information on moving to JPM from cfx click here](http://work.erikvold.com/jetpack/2014/08/07/cfx-to-jpm.html).